# Webform data tables name change d7 to d8 tables to delete records from

Tags: webforms

I have converted my d7 webforms to d8 with custom modules ... looks great
Previously I pulled data down from the database daily and deleted records from the webform_submissions and webform_submitted_data tables. (worked flawlessly for years)
With d8 the names are webform_submission and webform_submission_data.
Does anyone know if deleting the records from these two tables affects any other tables?  I intend to do as before... read daily, delete daily.
Thank you

Comment: No, in D8 webform submissions are entities and you should use the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api) to delete records.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you should use the 'Entity API' but if you are deleting 1000's of records I understand why you would want to do it using SQL.

Below are all the tables that are used to store webform submission related data.

- webform_scheduled_email
- webform_submission
- webform_submission_data
- webform_submission_log